# Core Data Concurrency: two big consecutive tasks separately from the main thread (in one of the big task requires many concurrent tasks)

Tags: macos, core-data, concurrency, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have pre-configuration file(with many parameters), the value of which I keep in CoreData.
Let's call it the first task:

```
Create new instance of NSManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContextVariable.
[parametersInFileArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                                        usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    [NSManagedObjectContextVariable performBlock:^{
        bla-bla-bla
        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName1 inManagedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContextVariable;
        [NSManagedObjectContextVariable save:&error];
    }
```

}

Then I want to process each value(stored earlier in CoreData) concurrency and save it to CoreData(entityName2 with relationship One-to-Any with entityName1). Let's call it the second task:

```
1.Create new instance of NSManagedObjectContext.
2.Get (NSArray *)fetchedObjects form entity("entityName1")
3.
 [fetchedObjects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(entityName1Class *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
      NSArray* newParameters = getManyNewParametersForObj(obj);
      [newParameters enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Parameter *param, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
         bla-bla-bla
        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName2 inManagedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContextVariable;
        [NSManagedObjectContextVariable save:&error];
    }

 }
```

So. I need execute Task 1 and Task 2 consecutively after each other. And separate from the main thread. The second task can not start until the first task is not finished.

In Task 2 I need to start *getManyNewParametersForObj+insertNewObjectForEntityForName+save* for each element from fetchedObjects(Obj) concurrency. Is a long operations(get Parameters from Net) and they do not depend on each other.

On every save in Task 1 and Task 2, I update NSTableView(Observe NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification).

I am very confused by dispatch_apply, performBlock, enumerateObjectsUsingBlock, enumerateObjectsUsingBlock, enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent, semaphoreWait, semaphoreBlock, blockUntilWait, serialQueue, parallelQueue etc.

Advise me how to do what I need.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) and [SMC](http://smc.sourceforge.net)?

*MagicalRecord* can help with the creating of contexts, saving in a block (other thread) and the merging back into the parent context.

So to setup a context and thread becomes;

`[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext)`

The block will be execute on its own thread using its own context. Further you can define a completion block that will perform on the main thread. This way you have feedback between your background thread and the main thread. And you avoid going into semaphores.

*SMC* is a Finite State Machine compiler for Objective C and other languages. It might take a little time to understand their syntax and their way of implementing a FSM, but it is definitely worth the upfront effort. Once implemented maintenance and changes will become really easy. [Eitan Suez](http://smc.sourceforge.net/slides/SMC_Tutorial.pdf) has produced a great tutorial PDF.

With SMC define a `state` for each of your tasks. Each state will have an `entry action`. The `entry action` will be the method containing the code that you show in your question.

At the end of `State 1` or lets call it `Task 1`, you fire the `transition` to the next state. The FSM will switch over and will perform the entry action of the next defined state, lets say `Task 2`. This way `Task 1` performs before `Task 2`.

FSM does not support parallel sub tasks out of the box. If you want to run the subtasks of super task 2 in parallel, then you would need to monitor completion of each sub task. I do this with three counters.

- `totalTasks` it the overall number of subtasks started
- `goodTasks` increments when a subtasks has finished without error
- `failedTasks` increments when a subtask has encountered a problem.

Now, when `goodTasks + failedTasks == totalTasks` then all subtasks of supertask 2 have finished. If `failedTasks == 0` then all went well.
A `failedTask` can make the FSM to switch to an error handling state, for example.

There are other Finite State Machine implementations around but I found SMC to be really flexible.